# Определить характеристики компьютера по JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, можно ли с помощью JS или других веб технологий собрать данные о характеристиках (железе) компьютера, и отправить на сервер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, благо, JS на это не способен, так как это бы нарушило политику безопасности пользователя. Из характеристик о железе Вы можете узнать только размеры экрана.

На это способны браузеры, вплоть до определения уровня заряда на ноутбуке.

Советую вам копать в сторону взаимодействия вашего JS-кода с установленными расширениями.

Answer (score 2):

Свойство navigator.hardwareConcurrency определяет количество ядер процессора.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorConcurrentHardware/hardwareConcurrency

Answer (score 0):

### ActiveX and screen

Узнать хар-ки системы из браузера поможет **ActiveX** который доступен исключительно в IE,
 позволяет работать с приложениями системы, 
 другими словами из браузера вы можете запустить калькулятор, блокнот, cmd и т.д.

Тут уже на ваше усмотрение как вы получите данные о системе, например можно запустить с **systeminfo**, а после направить результат себе по почте.
Нативными средствами JS можно узнать только размер окна браузера, цветовую палитру и еще пару мелочей:

```
/* Ширина, высота, цветовая палитра ( window.screen )*/
var screenWidth = window.screen.width,
    screenHeight = window.screen.height,
    screenDepthColor = window.screen.colorDepth

console.warn(screenWidth + " x " + screenHeight + "\n Цветовая палитра: "+ screenDepthColor +" bpp" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let gl = document.createElement( 'canvas' ).getContext( 'webgl' ),
    ext = gl.getExtension( 'WEBGL_debug_renderer_info' );

// videocard name, directx, ...
console.log( gl.getParameter( ext.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL ) );
```